# Need help in making an automatic battery cut-off switch

Tags: transistors, batteries, solar-charge-controller

[image: Block Diagram of the circuit]

I want help in making a automatic cut-off circuit to stop charging of the battery when the potential across the battery reaches 13.3 Volts. The problem is that I want to cut-off the Solar panel from circuit by measuring the potential of the battery.
The battery that I'm using is a 12V bike battery rated 9AH/10HR.
If you have any other suggestions then please tell.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is shove a MOSFET in series with the Solar Panel, and use a comparator to toggle it on and off. A very simple way to show that would be:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNaDzp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is incredibly simplified but it should provide a good starting point to work from. You can set your Vref to whatever you want, and monitor the battery voltage so when it hits a certain threshold, the comparator toggles the MOSFET, which in turn will switch the Solar Panel on and off.